# Upgrade 2006 iMac to install El Captain

Tags: macos, mac, cpu

I have an iMac from 2006, with OS X 10.6.8. My kid is using it to make simple movies in iMovie. But its seriously dated. I have a Bunch of other Core 2 Duo Processors, which are faster than the 1.8 Ghz processor it has. What I want to know is, if I put a faster processor, into this machine will it be able to install OS X "El Captain" when I tried to upgrade previously, a window appeared, stating that El Capitan, required Core 2 Duo, i3, i5, or i7.

Comment: There's a CPU upgrade guide here - http://www.tekrevue.com/stayin-alive-upgrading-cpu-hard-drive-ram-2006-imac/ though it won't help you upgrade to a 64-bit kernel

Answer (score 2):

Your iMac does not meet the requirements for El Captain. Although it states that some general requirements are:

1. OS X v10.6.8 or later
2. 2GB of memory
3. 8.8GB of available storage

There are also hardware requirements that your iMac does not meet. It states that for an iMac it needs to be a *mid 2007 model or later.*

I'm not sure how they determine the hardware requirements, to make sure that your model is "new enough." Knowing Apple, I have a feeling that simply putting in a new processor will not enable you to install the El Captain update. I'm sure they use some sort of model number, serial number, or part number in the system to determine the model year of your iMac. You can check out more on that [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201634)

Here are the [technical specifications for El Captain](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP728?locale=en_US) from Apple's website.

Comment: IMO, its just a way to force Mac users to purchase a new machine.

Comment: @Keltari Yes, yes. Since Apple doesn't go out of their way to explain every little detail, it *must* be because they're trying to screw their customers. Just FYI, the 2006 iMac used a 32-bit processor and El Capitan is a 64-bit operating system. THAT's why it won't run on older hardware.  And really why should it?  If a PC user complained that the latest version of Windows won't run on their NINE year-old PC, wouldn't you tell them it's time for a new computer? It's not realistic to expect Microsoft to support my Pentium 4 with 1Gig of RAM. And we shouldn't expect Apple to either.